# list files with first char within specific range

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

I need to list all files that have first char within a specific range.

If I use Powershell I can do this with

```
gci [a-c]*
```

How can I do it from command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following command:

```
dir /b | findstr /R "^[a-c].*"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's perfect. :) I can use even different ranges. ^[a-c|e-h].*". Thanks again.

Comment: Can you explain me why it's necessary the dot after ]?

Comment: This is a regular expression meaning "anything that starts from a-c range followed by zero or more of any characters (the dot)". I'm used to specifying the regular expressions that way, but actually **findstr** util doesn't require using the full syntax here, so you may omit the dot and the asterisk.